# Advice on reducing runtime for a Google Apps Script data move action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm wondering if you'd be able to help me reduce the runtime on a small little bit of code I've written. It feels very inefficient, but being a noob, I'm really not sure on the best way to make it better. Any advice is appreciated!

The premise is a very simple on-call tool. There are Slots 1 through to 4.

Users can put their start time, name and end time in any of the 4 available slots.

As users finish at different times, it can lead to it looking a little messy - such as Slots 1 and 4 having data, but Slots 2-3 being empty.

In order to make it look a little neater, I made a bit of code to check if the cell value is "None" (which I have another script to change the blank value to "None", for continuity), and if so, it moves it down the line (a conveyor belt-like system).

This runs a total of 4 times within the same function, to ensure it catches any possible combination of slots filled.

For some reason, I'm having an issue entering the code here (it screws up the formatting), so I've included screenshots, and a pastebin of the code:
Code Screenshot 1
[image: Code Screenshot 1]
Code Screenshot 2
[image: Code Screenshot 2]

[Pastebin full copy of code with correct formatting](https://pastebin.com/mFkVZiy4)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4");
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4");
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4");
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4");
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4')

          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}
 }

function conveyor() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
    var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
    var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
    var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue();
    var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
    var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
    var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
    var U4 = s.getRange('CK4')

      if (User3Name == 'None'){
      FourtoThree();
      }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


      if (User2Name == 'None'){
      ThreetoTwo();
      }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


      if (User1Name == 'None'){
      TwotoOne();
      }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue();
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4')

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue();
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4')

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue();
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4')

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}
  }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOVE SCRIPTS //

function TwotoOne() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
          .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4:I6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('K4:Q6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('S4:Y6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};

function ThreetoTwo() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};

function FourtoThree() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CC4:CI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CK4:CQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CS4:CY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('CC4:CI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('CK4:CQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('CS4:CY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

    };

RAW Paste Data
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4");
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4");
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4");
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4"); 
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4') 

          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');} 
 }

function conveyor() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
    var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
    var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
    var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue(); 
    var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
    var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
    var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
    var U4 = s.getRange('CK4') 

      if (User3Name == 'None'){
      FourtoThree();
      }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


      if (User2Name == 'None'){
      ThreetoTwo();
      }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


      if (User1Name == 'None'){
      TwotoOne();
      }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue(); 
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4') 

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue(); 
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4') 

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

 var User1Name = s.getRange("K4").getDisplayValue();
 var User2Name = s.getRange("AK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User3Name = s.getRange("BK4").getDisplayValue();
 var User4Name = s.getRange("CK4").getDisplayValue(); 
 var U1 = s.getRange('K4')
 var U2 = s.getRange('AK4')
 var U3 = s.getRange('BK4')
 var U4 = s.getRange('CK4') 

  if (User3Name == 'None'){
  FourtoThree();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}


  if (User2Name == 'None'){
  ThreetoTwo();
  }
          if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}

  if (User1Name == 'None'){
  TwotoOne();
  }
        if (U1.isBlank()){
        U1.setValue('None');}

        if (U2.isBlank()){
        U2.setValue('None');}

        if (U3.isBlank()){
        U3.setValue('None');}

        if (U4.isBlank()){
        U4.setValue('None');}
  }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOVE SCRIPTS //

function TwotoOne() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
          .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4:I6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('K4:Q6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('S4:Y6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};

function ThreetoTwo() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AC4:AI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AK4:AQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AS4:AY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};

function FourtoThree() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('BC4:BI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CC4:CI6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BK4:BQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CK4:CQ6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('BS4:BY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('CS4:CY6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('CC4:CI6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('CK4:CQ6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('CS4:CY6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

The conveyor code is under `function conveyor()`, and the movement code is under `function TwotoOne()`, `function ThreetoTwo()` and `function FourtoThree()`.

The issue with the code (apart from it being super basic, but that's the joys of being a noob) is that the execution of `function conveyor()` is that the runtime is approximately 15 seconds.

Is there anything you'd please advise to cut down the runtime?

If you'd like to see the code in action, or take a physical look at the code, please go ahead and see the [Google Spreadsheet Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qKTdHJOWclML3Ja48QBAbRcAWTc6Ss09u4HITMLZK80/edit?usp=sharing). Put any combination of info in each slot, tap "RUN", and it will always move them back down to be in order (so 2 and 3 will become 1 and 2, 1 and 4 will become 1 and 2, 1,3 and 4 will become 1,2 and 3, etc.).

(This is a full copy (not original) of my spreadsheet, with no confidential info and only the basic code required to function. Feel free to tinker it or destroy it as much as needed. There is a full backup. Also, once a solution has been found, I'll restore the original version so future askers will be able to see the initial code) and see my issue.

Thanks again for your time. Let me know if you have any other questions and I'll do my best to explain!

Comment: *EDIT* Not sure why I copy/pasted the same bit of code 4 times, as it only needs to be 3. I'm not going to move anything from Slot 1, so it only needs to move data from Slots 4,3 and 2. Removing this got the runtime down to about 11 seconds. Any further advice would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you should "move" this question to [codereview.se] (meaning delete here, post there but first checkout the tour and how to ask help article on that site. If you want to keep it here, IMHO, you should create a [mcve], add a description of your search/research efforts (maybe create a new question rather than editing this one).

Comment: You need to use arrays. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices This will reduce it to less than 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
* Moves Filled Slots to occupy the left empty slots
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function conveyorBelt() {
  var rangList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRangeList(['K4','AK4','BK4','CK4']); // Four slot entries
  var rngArr = rangList.getRanges(); //getEachSlotRange
  for(var i=0;i<rngArr.length;i++) { //Loop over each Slot
    if (rngArr[i].isBlank()) { //if current slot is empty,
      for (var j= i+1;j<rngArr.length;j++) { //Loop over other slots to the right to find the  next non empty slot
        if (!rngArr[j].isBlank()) { //next non empty slot
          var targetRange = rngArr[i].offset(0,-8,3,23);//Expand range to full slot(23Columns and 3rows)
          var sourceRange = rngArr[j].offset(0,-8,3,23);//Expand range to full slot(23Columns and 3rows)
          sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,false); //Paste Normal Ignoring Color Formatting
          sourceRange.clearContent()
          break;

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```